# ReactJS Imports not working blank webpage

Tags: javascript, reactjs, django, django-rest-framework, django-react

I am a beginner learning ReactJS and was trying to make a full-stack quiz web application using DjangoRestFramework+ReactJS.

> **The Problem**

I am not seeing anything rendering to my webpage when I try using imports. I am not getting any errors, but my web page is blank.

> **My Files**

Here is my App.JS.

```
import { render } from "react-dom";
import HomePage from "./HomePage";
import GameJoinPage from "./GameJoinPage";

export default class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <HomePage />
    );
  }
}

const appDiv = document.getElementById("app");
render(<App />, appDiv);
```

My Index.html

```
<! DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-9">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Quiz App</title>
    {% load static %}
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700&display=swap"
    />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static "css/index.css" %}"
    /> 
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="main">
      <div id="app">
      </div>
    </div>
    <script src="{% static "frontend/main.js" %}"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

And my HomePage file

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import GameJoinPage from "./GameJoinPage";
import CreateRoomPage from "./CreateGamePage";
import { 
  BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route, Link, Redirect} from "react-router-dom";

export default class HomePage extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
  render(){
    return (
      <Router>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/"><p>This is the home page</p></Route>
          <Route path="/join" component={GameJoinPage} />
          <Route path="/create" component={CreateGamePage} />
        </Switch>
    </Router>
    );

  }
}
```

> **What I tried**

When I put `<h1>Hello World</h1>` in place of `<HomePage \>`, It rendered the `Hello World` to the webpage as expected.
But when I put the `<HomePage \>` or any other tag such as `<CreateGamePage \>` In `App.js`, nothing renders to the webpage. I am not getting any errors on Webpack compilation.

Comment: What do you see in web developer tools, in the response to the request? Do you have any errors in the Django server? I can recommend [good tutorial about Django+React](https://saasitive.com/django-react/boilerplate/). It is using decoupled Django and React.

Comment: Thank you! I checked my console and found out that I had misspelled an import.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out! The issue was not with my code, it was a misspelling in my `HomePage.js` file. I was trying to import `CreateRoomPage` from `CreateGamePage` when in fact in `CreateRoomPage` did not exist, the correct one was `CreateGamePage`. Thank you all for the helpful responses!

> ***Before***
> `HomePage.JS`

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import GameJoinPage from "./GameJoinPage";
import CreateGamePage from "./CreateGamePage"; // Now its correct!
import { Switch, Route, Link, Redirect } from "react-router-dom";

export default class HomePage extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/" render={() => <p>This is the home page</p>} />
        <Route path="/join" component={GameJoinPage} />
        <Route path="/create" component={CreateGamePage} />
      </Switch>
    );
  }
```

> ***After***

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import GameJoinPage from "./GameJoinPage";
import CreateRoomPage from "./CreateGamePage";
import { Switch, Route, Link, Redirect } from "react-router-dom";

export default class HomePage extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/" render={() => <p>This is the home page</p>} />
        <Route path="/join" component={GameJoinPage} />
        <Route path="/create" component={CreateGamePage} />
      </Switch>
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with id #main

```
const appDiv = document.getElementById("main");
```

and just change **HomePage.js** to check

```
<Switch>
    <Route exact path="/" render={()=> <h2>render default page</h2>}/>
    <Route path="/join" component={GameJoinPage} />
    <Route path="/create" component={CreateGamePage} />
</Switch>
```

Comment: @VahidAktar I'm still seeing a blank page. What difference would changing the id to `main` make? It's the parent div.

Answer (score 1):

Add router to the parent element

```
import { render } from "react-dom";
import HomePage from "./HomePage";
import GameJoinPage from "./GameJoinPage";
import { BrowserRouter as Router } from "react-router-dom";

export default class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <HomePage />
      </Router>
    );
  }
}

const appDiv = document.getElementById("app");
render(<App />, appDiv);
```

Change the HomePage file to

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import GameJoinPage from "./GameJoinPage";
import CreateRoomPage from "./CreateGamePage";
import { Switch, Route, Link, Redirect } from "react-router-dom";

export default class HomePage extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/" render={() => <p>This is the home page</p>} />
        <Route path="/join" component={GameJoinPage} />
        <Route path="/create" component={CreateGamePage} />
      </Switch>
    );
  }
}
```